# How to stack tensors after reduce_mean in variant size gather in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example, I have the tensor

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [4,5]])
```

Then I have a list of aggregation indices

```
idx = [[0,1],[2], [3, 4]]
```

And apply to the `x` and take the mean of each individual tensor

```
y = []
for i in idx:
  y.append(tf.reduce_mean(tf.gather(x, i, 0), 0))
```

Finally, stack them togather

```
y = tf.stack(y, 0)
```

I wanna the results to be 

`tensor([[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]])`

It has problems, the for loop is not efficient, could anyone help me to resolve it?

Comment: What's the problem you mentioned?

Comment: @giser_yugang How to get rid of the for loop?

Comment: Maybe you need to try [Ragged Tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors) `tensorflow>=1.13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you ? Please verify. Note that it prints floats for some reason and the version of Tensorflow is `1.13`. I am also not sure how efficient this is compared to yours as I don't have a microbenchmark.

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [4,5]])

print( sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(tf.gather(x,tf.ragged.constant([[0,1],[2], [3, 4]]),0),1) ))
```

prints

```
[[1. 2.]
 [2. 3.]
 [4. 5.]]
```